# MySQL - Group by range

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I need to count the records within value ranges.

For example: for the set `1, 7, 9, 23, 33, 35, 1017`

`select count(myvalue) group by round(myvalue / 10)` gives something like:

```
0-10  -> 3
10-20 -> 0
20-30 -> 1
30-40 -> 2
1010-1020 -> 1
```

This works fine. However, I need to set an upper limit, so that MySQL returns `40+ --> 1` ?
How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either sum the values on the client side or use two queries, possibly with `union`, to fetch the data, e.g.:

```
select round(myvalue / 10), count(myvalue) from table where myvalue < 40 group by round(myvalue / 10)
union
select '40+', count(myvalue) from table where myvalue >= 40
```

It is absolutely possible to write it in a single query with subqueries or convoluted conditions but it just wouldn't be as simple and maintainable.

Comment: I just hoped that was a way to define an upper and lower limit (e.g. 20- / 40+) for doing the query in a generic manner.

Answer (score 4):

```
select t.myvalue as [range], count(*) as [occurences]
from (
  select myvalue,
   case when myvalue >= 0 and myvalue< 10 then '0-9'
   when myvalue >= 10 and myvalue< 20 then '10-19'
   when myvalue >= 20 and myvalue< 20 then '20-29'
   when myvalue >= 30 and myvalue< 40 then '30-39'
   else '40+' end as range
 from t) t
group by t.myvalue
```

Comment: It did not worked any idea? SELECT t.salary as range, count(*) as num_employee  
FROM
(SELECT salary, 
CASE WHEN salary < = 50000 THEN 'Lowest'
        WHEN salary > 50000 and salary < = 70000 THEN 'Medium'
        ELSE 'Highest' END AS RANGE
 FROM employee_salary) t
GROUP BY t.salary

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT case 
   when myvalue >= 0 and myvalue< 10 then '0-9'
   when myvalue >= 10 and myvalue< 20 then '10-19'
   when myvalue >= 20 and myvalue< 20 then '20-29'
   when myvalue >= 30 and myvalue< 40 then '30-39'
   else '40+' 
   end as range
 from t 
group by range
```

Comment: it would be helpful for the OP if you could edit your answer and put it in context to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this solution that borrows from both pilsetnieks and Jayram's solutions:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    IF (myvalue >= 40; -1; ROUND(myvalue / 10) AS range
FROM t
GROUP BY range
```

Comment: At least in MySQL, `range` is a reserved word: [9.3 Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)